# Trying to show that a vector value function has equal mixed partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f: R^n \to R^n$. $||x||$ is Euclidean norm. Define $f(x) = xg(||x||)$. where $g: [0, \infty) \to R^n$ is differentiable on $(0, \infty)$. $g$ is not constant. I want to show that every $i \neq j$, $\frac{ \partial f_i}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i } $.

#### My Effort:

Notice $f_i(x_1,...,x_n) = x_i g_i(||x||) $. Hence

$$ \frac{ \partial f_i}{\partial x_j} = \frac{x_jx_i}{||x||} \frac{ d g_i(||x||)}{d||x||}
$$

and

$$ \frac{ \partial f_j}{\partial x_i} = \frac{x_ix_j}{||x||} \frac{ d g_j(||x||)}{d||x||}
$$

So, all remains to show that $g_i' = g_j'$. How can I show this?

Comment: If both $x,g(\|x\|)\in\Bbb R^n$ then what is $xg(\|x\|)$? Should it be done kind of inner product? The whole thing would make much more sense and definitely be equivalent if $g:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both $x,g(\|x\|)\in\Bbb R^n$ then what is $xg(\|x\|)$? Should it be some kind of inner product? The whole thing would make much more sense and definitely be equivalent if $g:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$

Then you would have $f_i=x_ig(\|x\|)$ thus:

$\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}=\frac{x_ix_j}{\|x\|}g'(\|x\|)$ and

$\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}=\frac{x_jx_i}{\|x\|}g'(\|x\|)$

Which are the same.